# Photon2 Unity2D How to send float with RPC

Tags: unity, photon

I have big problem in my code .. I want to spawn obstacle exactly on the same position as on the server is spawned so I made rpc Method and tried to pass random variable of float , but when i run the game obstacles are spawned on the diffrent position. I am loosing a lot of time to get it done but I still can not find solution.

Here is the code

```html
   [PunRPC]
    void RPC_SpawnColumn(Vector3 position)
    {
        // Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        Debug.Log("THIS IS SPAWNYPOSITION" + spawnYPosition);

        Instantiate(prefab, new Vector2(9, spawnYPosition), Quaternion.identity);

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        //print("Are we here");
        if (collision.GetComponent<ColumnsMultiplayer>() != null)
        {
            
            print("Or are we here");
            if (SpawnOnce)
            {
                spawnYPosition = Random.Range(-3.36f, 2.98f);
                
               
               
                photonView.RPC("RPC_SpawnColumn", RpcTarget.Others,new Vector3(9, spawnYPosition));  // this is 
              
            }
                //SpawnColumn();
                
            SpawnOnce = false;


        }
    }
```

Thank you so much for reading post.

Edit: I need to send spawnYPosition  from method two to method one and spawn it with same position of spawnYPosition  in the second method.

Comment: It looks like you accept a `position` argument in the RPC call, but none of your code in that method actually reads or uses that `position` variable. Is this intentional? Have you tried actually reading & using the value that was passed from the caller?

Comment: @DMGregory , 
Can you tell me how i can use it? or how i can read the spawnYPosition = Random.Range(-3.36f, 2.98f); in the first method, i mean how i can read spawnYPosition  and pass it into rpc spawn method on the variable of the "spawnYPosition"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might need a refresher on function arguments.

When you define a function like this:

```
void RPC_SpawnColumn(Vector3 position)
```

You're saying "I will accept as input a `Vector3` value, and I will call that value `position` inside the body of this method" - this `position` variable is called an argument to the function, and you can use it like other variables inside its body.

Now, when you call the function (remotely) like this:

```
photonView.RPC("RPC_SpawnColumn", RpcTarget.Others, new Vector3(9, spawnYPosition));
```

You're saying "Call the function, and pass it the value `(9, spawnYPosition, 0)` to use as the `position` argument"

So, inside the body of `RPC_SpawnColumn`, if you want the value of `spawnYPosition` which you passed as the y coordinate of the `position` argument, you can get it by reading `position.y`.

So it looks like you want to change this line, which makes up a new vector with whatever value we have in `spawnYPosition` locally:

```
Instantiate(prefab, new Vector2(9, spawnYPosition), Quaternion.identity);
```

to this line, which uses the `position` that was sent to us via the RPC call (including `spawnYPosition` in the y component):

```
Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Comment: I marked it as answer so i need to make it something like hits in rpc method::
 void RPC_SpawnColumn(Vector3 position)
    {
        

        Instantiate(prefab,position, Quaternion.identity);

    }

Comment: When I use your solution it spawn objects on the diffrent positions .. It doesn't work in my case.. I hope you will send me email here : cikatuna@gmail.com ..... I dont have any other idea why it doesn't work... here is full code of obstacle spawn with your edit.  LINK to fullcode now: https://pastebin.com/mHPf7hkA

Comment: Users here will not troubleshoot your problem via email. It is your responsibility to ensure that your question contains a minimal, complete, verifiable example of the problem so that users can validate solutions without access to all of your code or back-and-forth discussion.

Comment: One guy said to me i need to use instantiate in photonnetwork not rpc

Comment: Your question was "how to send float" which is answered here. If you want to do network instantiation, first [read the docs about how to do that](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/instantiation) and work through some existing guides & tutorials to get the hang of it. If you run into trouble, you can post a new question about the specific issue you've run into.